# Knitr 1.4.3 Fails to install when deploying ShinyApp using GitActions

Tags: r, github, shiny, github-actions, shinydashboard

**Summary**

Deployment of a shiny app using git actions workflow started to fail on **July 6, 2023** because my program can't instal knitr 1.4.3 package and deploy the app.
App runs just fine and deploys on the local machine.
The issue must be with the way I interact with the github environment.

**Explanation**

I have a shiny app that is scheduled to be deployed using github actions workflow on a daily basis. Recently automatic updates have been failing because of issues with the knitr package. Apparently, shiny would not compile without it, so it has been a major issue for me.

I am attaching my github_action.yml file:

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 5 * * *' # every day at midnight
  push:
    branches: main
  workflow_dispatch:

name: Update and Upload FBref data 

jobs:
  build-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    permissions:
        contents: write
        
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Quarto
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/setup@v2
        
      - name: Setup R
        uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2
        with:
          r-version: '4.3.1' # The R version to download (if necessary) and use.
          
      - name: Install packages
        uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2
        with:
            packages:
              any::devtools
              any::tidyverse
              any::plotly
              any::rvest
              any::xml2
              any::worldfootballR
              any::aws.s3
              any::rlang
              any::data.table
              any::shinythemes
              any::shiny
              any::shinydashboard
              any::shinyjs
              any::DT
              any::feather
              any::secret
              any::rsconnect
              any::stringr
              any::kableExtra
              knitr@1.4.2
               
      - name: Execute R Script
        env:
            access_key: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_KEY }}
            secret_key: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}
            aws_region: ${{ secrets.REGION }}
            bucket_name: ${{secrets.BUCKET_NAME}}
            
            shiny_acc: ${{secrets.SHINY_ACC_NAME}}
            shiny_secret: ${{secrets.SHINY_SECRET_TOKEN}}
            shiny_token: ${{secrets.SHINY_TOKEN}}
        run: |
            Rscript Collect\ Data/Update\ Data/Refresh\ Data\ Pull.R
            Rscript deploy.R
          
      - name: Render document
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/render@v2
        with:
          to: gfm
          path: README.qmd
          
      
          
      - name: Setup git config
        run: |
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions Bot"
          git config user.email "<>"
          
      - name: Commit
        run: |
          git add .
          git commit -m "Updated report"
          git push origin main
```

When I review the log of a failed run, I can see that the error happens when I run deploy.R script.
I successfully install packages, including knitr, prior to collecting the data and deploying the app using deploy.R script.

However, when I use deployApp() function in the script, I can see this output in the log:

```
ℹ Capturing R dependencies with renv
✔ Found 164 dependencies
✔ Created 6,930,165b bundle
ℹ Uploading bundle...
✔ Uploaded bundle with id 7529597
── Deploying to server ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Waiting for task: 1324032606
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Building image: 8912218
  building: Installing system dependencies
  building: Fetching packages
  error: Building package: knitr
```

And the error message is:

```
Error: Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1324032607 failed: Error building image: Error fetching knitr (1.43) source. Error downloading package source: Unsupported url scheme: CRAN/src/contrib/knitr_1.43.tar.gz
```

Does anybody know how to point deployApp() function to a different build of knitr package, or have suggestions for a general workaround. This seem to be an issue beginning July 6, 2023.

Thanks!

I tried different ways of specifying versions of knitr to install, and different ways to instal the package. All lead to the same outcome